# Identify flash IC by ID

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, flash

I read flash device ID as following:

```
Manufacturer: c8
Device: 4013
```

- Is this enough information in order to uniquely identify the IC?
- Is there some web repository where I can check which device I have in hand, based on that ID?

---

**Update:**

Thanks to @RespawnedFluff answer below I found out [this list](https://github.com/flashrom/flashrom/blob/staging/flashchips.h).

Is there some standard way to identify IC by Manufacturer/Device ID?
Otherwise, how do manufacturers prevent ID collisions (same ID to different devices) when they allocate these IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of googling suggests this is a GigaDevice GD25Q40. The most reliable source for that info probably being http://www.flashrom.org/pipermail/flashrom/2012-April/009060.html (Note that it's marked untested.)

A bit later it was [renamed](http://patchwork.coreboot.org/patch/3963/) to GD25Q40(B), which is apparently the same thing. The manufacturer, which has a super-slow website (as far downloading data sheets goes), has a page for it http://www.gigadevice.com/product/detail/5/119.html

EDIT: In response to the question in the comment, there's a JEDEC standard (currently [JEP106AP](https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/results/taxonomy%3A3268)) doling out the flash mfg. numbers. GigaDevice has 8c assinged in there. Note that there are some "continuation bytes" now because they've ran out of mfg. ids in the original scheme. As for the device ID, I think they're (still) vendor-specific, i.e. it's up to the manufacturer to come up with them in way that doesn't cause incompatibilities/problems with their other chips. I'm not aware of a JEDEC (or other) centralized registry for device ids, except as it happens ad-hoc in flashing software. Some manufacturers make it easy to confirm the device id by putting it in their datasheet (e.g. Micron does that), but there's no device id in the aforementioned GigaDevice data sheet.

Comment: That seems correct (GigaDevice: 4Mbit/512Kbyte GD25Q40). However, there must be some standard way to identify IC by Manufacturer/Device ID (other than googling it). Otherwise, how do manufacturers prevent ID collisions (same ID to different devices) when they allocate these IDs?